# how to hide development assets in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, assets

I have a folder structure for my js and css-files in the public folder like this:

```
public
    js
        dev
        prod
    css
        dev
        prod
```

Basically the dev files contain the not-minified files. where as the prod folder contains the minified files. 
But actually I would prefer to not have the dev-files publicly available and load them only when I as a developer am in dev-mode.

How do i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You have no need for `prod` version of those files and  should delegate the creation of those to `Assetic` which compiles them, by default, to `/web/{css|js}/` directory.

Read more about `Assetic` here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/index.html

Pay special attention to `Filters` section..

Answer (score 0):

a quick and simply hack could be to have your dev assets somewhere else, maybe

```
web/custom/assetsDev
```

and in the Ressources/Public folder you make a symlink on all dev machines to the dev assets like:

```
  ln -s  js/  /yourProject/web/custom/assetsDev/js
```

dont forget to put both directorys in

> .gitignore

dont know if that suits for this case, but in theory it should be working and you dont have to configurate anything inside the app